# External table is not in the expected format thrown only in certain situations

Tags: c#

I am trying to open an xlsx file and I get the External table is not in the expected format only when I open from a certain area of my app. So it works just fine if I call it from 1 area, but then I do the same thing from a different part of the app, calling the same code block, and it throws that exception. Same code block. Same excel file.

```
string connectionString = "Provider="+ GetProvider(fileName) +"; data source=" + fileName + "; " + GetExtendedProperties(fileName);

                using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    connection.Open();

                    using (DataTable schemaTable = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
                                                                                  new object[] { null, null, null, "TABLE" }))
                    {
                        if (schemaTable != null && schemaTable.Rows != null)
                        {
                            List<string> validTables = schemaTable.Rows.OfType<DataRow>().Select(row => (string)row["TABLE_NAME"]).ToList();

                            validTables.ForEach(table =>
                            {
                                if (table.Contains('$'))
                                {
                                    results.WorkSheets.Add(table.Trim('\'', '$'));
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    results.NamedRanges.Add(table);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                }
```

My connection string:

Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=C:\moses\BLANKTest\Table.xlsx; Extended Properties="Excel 12.0 Xml";

Also tried the connection string taking out the "Xml" at the end. No luck.

Not sure what is going on here.

Comment: There must be *something* different.  The state of the application has changed, or the file is already open by another process, or some function/variable you are using has a different value than you expected, etc.

Comment: Yeah, you would think there is something different. I have changed it to check separate files. So area 1 uses one file and has no problems, area 2 uses a different file and still has issues. So that rules out the file already being opened by another process. The only thing I can think of is app state I guess. The code is above and it is pretty basic.

Comment: What do you mean by called from a different area?  Is this a utility function that gets called by two different buttons?  What does the calling code look like in both examples?

Comment: The calling code is pretty similar. Both use MEF to resolve an instance of the interface and just call the method you see above.